# How do I edit the value of a specific node in XML when there are multiple nodes with the same name?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to edit a specific node in an XML document. I have the following XML data:

```
<Items xmlns="http://foo.com/blah/blah">
  <Item>
    <Format>1</Format>
    <Name>Edit this one</Name>
    <MetaDataDictionary>
      <MetaData>
        <Name>Do not edit this one</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
      </MetaData>
    </MetaDataDictionary>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Format>1</Format>
    <Name>Edit this one</Name>
    <MetaDataDictionary>
      <MetaData>
        <Name>Do not edit this one</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
      </MetaData>
    </MetaDataDictionary>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

I want to append a number to each `Item/Name` node content but not to the `Metadata/Name` nodes, save the file off as `test_n.xml` and repeat n number of times.

The code I'm using seems to get me what I want for the `Item/Name` node and saved the file(s) correctly but it also updates the `Metadata/Name` nodes and I do not want that value to be updated. I understand the problem is in the `navigator.Select` call but I just don't know how to update one and skip the other.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("at", "http://foo.com/blah/blah");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//at:Name", manager))
    {
        var currValue = nav.Value;
        nav.SetValue(currValue + " " + i);
    }
   doc.Save("test_" + i + ".xml");
}
```

In the end I'd like it to be:

```
<Items xmlns="http://foo.com/blah/blah">
  <Item>
    <Format>1</Format>
    <Name>Edit this one 0</Name>
    <MetaDataDictionary>
      <MetaData>
        <Name>Do not edit this one</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
      </MetaData>
    </MetaDataDictionary>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Format>1</Format>
    <Name>Edit this one 0</Name>
    <MetaDataDictionary>
      <MetaData>
        <Name>Do not edit this one</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
      </MetaData>
    </MetaDataDictionary>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Comment: What is the XPath `//at:Name` suppose to mean? I don't know the `at` prefix and I wasn't able to find it in any documentation.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer in case it solved your issue. It will help others to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't select all `name` tags, instead select only `name` tags which are children of `/Items/Item` tag.

The XPath query would look like `/Items/Item/Name`.

You can [test it here](http://xpather.com/UlZlkcZD). See the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) for details.

Comment: With a little help here and some more digging I was able to resolve this.  I needed to add the namespace prefix in each tag.  So the search string had to become "/at:Items/at:Item/at:Name" I found an example of the syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.select?view=netframework-4.8